# How to get coordinates of element during animation in SVG

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I have such code:

```
<defs>
    <g id="g0">
        <circle cx="0" cy="1" r="16" fill="blue" id="pr0" stroke-width="0" stroke="#2986dc"/>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="14" fill="red" id="pp0" />
    </g>
</defs>
<use x="603" y="484" id="u0" href="#g0">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" id="t0" dur="30s" repeatCount="indefinite" from="0 494 494" to="360 494 494"/>
</use>
```

How can i get coordinates of group during animation using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The [SVG 1.2 Micro DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/svgudom.html) provides the `get*PresentationTrait*()` class of methods for accessing animated values, but I don't think they are supported yet by browsers. So maybe the easiest way would be to resort to JavaScript animation.

Comment: I guess I was slightly off with my answer, but I found there actually *is* a way to find the current position using `getScreenCTM()`, which returns the animated value of the transformation matrix. I currently don't have a working example, though.

Comment: JavaScript animation is not smooth :( It is looks good only if I animate vector objects. But when I try to animate raster images or  shapes filled by raster images (PNG, JPG) it looks very bad. Shapes have jittering and it looks unacceptable. But using native SVG animation such as animateMotion or animateTransform i get smooth good animation :)